# What's the actual use of 'fail' in JUnit test case?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

What's the actual use of 'fail' in JUnit test case?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Some cases where I have found it useful:

- mark a test that is incomplete, so it fails and warns you until you can finish it
- making sure an exception is thrown:

> ```
> try{
>   // do stuff...
>   fail("Exception not thrown");
> }catch(Exception e){
>   assertTrue(e.hasSomeFlag());
> }
> ```

Note:

Since JUnit4, there is a more elegant way to test that an exception is being thrown:
Use the annotation `@Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)`

However, this won't work if you also want to inspect the exception, then you still need `fail()`.

Comment: Consider this blog post about the relative merits of fail vs expected annotation: http://blog.jooq.org/2016/01/20/use-junits-expected-exceptions-sparingly/

Comment: @sleske "if you also want to inspect the exception, then you still need fail()" -- nope. ExpectedException is the way, see https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/exception-testing

Comment: @kraxor: True, didn't know about it when I wrote the answer (it probably wasn't even around then).

Answer (score 22):

Let's say you are writing a test case for a negative flow where the code being tested should raise an exception.

```
try{
   bizMethod(badData);
   fail(); // FAIL when no exception is thrown
} catch (BizException e) {
   assert(e.errorCode == THE_ERROR_CODE_U_R_LOOKING_FOR)
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I think the usual use case is to call it when no exception was thrown in a negative test.

Something like the following pseudo-code:

```
test_addNilThrowsNullPointerException()
{
    try {
        foo.add(NIL);                      // we expect a NullPointerException here
        fail("No NullPointerException");   // cause the test to fail if we reach this            
     } catch (NullNullPointerException e) {
        // OK got the expected exception
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do not check something in the catch block you can use the @ExpectedException(NullNullPointerException.class) method annotation to declare that you expect an exception (of a special kind).

Comment: @FrVaBe I may be incorrect, but that was not part of Junit back in 2010.

Answer (score 9):

I've used it in the case where something may have gone awry in my @Before method.

```
public Object obj;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Do some set up
    obj = new Object();
}

@Test
public void testObjectManipulation() {
    if(obj == null) {
        fail("obj should not be null");
     }

    // Do some other valuable testing
}
```

Comment: Yes, testing preconditions is good. However, if you want to make sure the `@Before` method succeeded, it's probably better to check it directly in that method. As a bonus, at least JUnit and TestNG will even report a different failure for errors from `@Before`/`@After` methods, so can see that the problem was not in the test itself.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I use the Fail method.

There are three states that your test case can end up in

1. Passed : The function under test executed successfully and returned
   data as expected
2. Not Passed : The function under test executed successfully but the
   returned data was not as expected
3. Failed : The function did not execute successfully and this was not

intended (Unlike negative test cases that expect a exception to
    occur).

If you are using eclipse there three states are indicated by a Green, Blue and red marker respectively.

I use the fail operation for the the third scenario.

e.g. : public Integer add(integer a, Integer b) { return new Integer(a.intValue() + b.intValue())}

1. Passed Case : a = new Interger(1), b= new Integer(2) and the function returned 3
2. Not Passed Case: a = new Interger(1), b= new Integer(2) and the function returned soem value other than 3
3. Failed Case : a =null , b= null and the function throws a NullPointerException

Comment: If you look at JUnit's source code, you'll see that assertions use `fail()`.

Answer (score 4):

I, for example, use `fail()` to indicate tests that are not yet finished (it happens); otherwise, they would show as successful.

This is perhaps due to the fact that I am unaware of some sort of incomplete() functionality, which exists in NUnit.

Answer (score 2):

In concurrent and/or asynchronous settings, you may want to verify that certain methods (e.g. delegates, event listeners, response handlers, you name it) are *not* called. Mocking frameworks aside, you can call `fail()` in those methods to fail the tests. Expired timeouts are another natural failure condition in such scenarios.

For example:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

service.asyncCall(someParameter, new ResponseHandler<SomeType>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SomeType result) {
        assertNotNull(result);
        // Further test assertions on the result
        latch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
        fail(exception.getMessage());
        latch.countDown();
    }
});

if ( !latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ) {
    fail("No response after 5s");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most important use case is probably exception checking.

While junit4 includes the [expected element](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html#expected()) for checking if an exception occurred, it seems like it isn't part of the newer junit5. Another advantage of using `fail()` over the `expected` is that you can combine it with `finally` allowing test-case cleanup.

```
dao.insert(obj);
try {
  dao.insert(obj);
  fail("No DuplicateKeyException thrown.");
} catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
  assertEquals("Error code doesn't match", 123, e.getErrorCode());
} finally {
  //cleanup
  dao.delete(obj);
}
```

As noted in another comment. Having a test to fail until you can finish implementing it sounds reasonable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short Junit 5 example that illustrates the difference between unit test failure and error. (Note that JUnit 5 has a `assertThrows(…)` method, so the use of `fail(…)` to indicate the absence of an exception is seldom needed.)

Let's say I have a method `deleteFileTree(Path fileTreeRoot)` to delete a directory even if it has files in it. My method works, except that the first time I wrote it I assumed there was a directory to delete. In the field I ran into a case where the directory didn't exist to begin with, and it threw a `NoSuchFileException`. I want this method to be idempotent (it's not a problem if we try to delete a directory that is missing, or if we delete the directory twice), so I fixed the problem. The integration test looks like this:

```java
@Test
void verifyDeleteFileTreeThrowsNoExceptionIfPathDoesNotExist(@TempDir Path tempDir) throws IOException {
  try {
    final Path missingDir = tempDir.resolve("missing");
    assertThat(Files.deleteFileTree(missingDir), is(missingDir));
  } catch(final NoSuchFileException noSuchFileException) {
    fail("Should not throw exception if path is already missing.", noSuchFileException);
  }
}
```

In this case the test was to make sure it did not throw `NoSuchFileException`; if it does, the test *fails*. But if some other exception is thrown, the test has an *error*, as the problem is something unexpected and unrelated to what I'm testing—i.e. the test is not working correctly.

If I had not have checked for `NoSuchFileException` and used `fail(…)`, the test would have indicated an error condition. This would not have been correct semantically, as the test was working correctly and had no error—rather, the method I was testing failed the test.