# When do we use method fail() in android testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, assert

In tutorial for testing android have found the method fail() which is from Asserts. So in which scenario this method could be useful?

Comment: For example, when an exception is triggered.

Comment: @cesarmarch could you give example of the test for that?

Comment: complicated boolean if(a&&b||c||d&&e) fail("oops");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the actual use of 'fail' in JUnit test case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869954/whats-the-actual-use-of-fail-in-junit-test-case)